# Does the TypeScript complier have the same browser support as I would have with babel preset-env

Tags: javascript, typescript

According to the [official guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide#typescript-react-conversion-guide), I could remove babel from our project if I'm getting compiling done with TypeScript.

Will my page support the same browsers as before, or do I need to replace this preset with something?

Comment: What browser support are you looking at? (New browsers or support for like IE 10?)

Comment: We don't support IE anymore, but from Edge on.

Answer (score 0):

For typescript to be compiled to handle modern browsers, removing babel-preset-ENV will ensure that browser support will be maintained.

If you don’t need ECMAScript 5 syntax, remove the Babel preset.

Modern browsers will be able to execute whatever Typescript has compiled.